# Porque não posso abrir a interface do MongoDB na porta : 28017?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, banco-de-dados

Instalei o mongo  na unidade C e fiz alguns testes de criação de dados e os persisti,depois consultei e lá estavam eles perfeitamente listados no prompt.
Ate ai tudo OK!
Abro o browser e digito `localhost:27017` e aparece a mensagem de sinal de vida:

```
It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
```

Mas quando tento `localhost:28017` só vejo:

```
Esta página da web não está disponível
```

O que devo fazer?

Comment: Vc configurou o painel web do MongoDb para responder à porta 28017?

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi Obrigado pela atenção. Como eu faria exatamente isso?Estou usando a versão 2.6.11

Comment: Nunca fiz, o caso é que, por padrão, o MongoDB configura seu websetup na porta 27017, não na porta 28017. Por isso vc recebe um 404, pois não há nenhuma aplicação web respondendo nesta porta.

Comment: O que você está a tentar fazer Pena? Se quiser consultar dados via browser, deve adicionar o commando `--rest` quando executar o mongo. Depois disso pode aceder através de `http://localhost: 28017/mydb/mycollection/` e aplicar os filtros que forem necessários.

Comment: @AndréVarandas Valeu amigo!!Sou iniciante no NOSQL,é que eu vi em um tutorial de instalação o cara navegando pela porta 27017 e tambem 28017,   e quando tentei fazer o mesmo, não consegui!! Ele não ensinou a fazer isso!!Onde eu digito o comando que você mencionou? Tennho dois terminais abertos um com o mongod e o outro com mongo onde eu trabalho visuallizando os dados!

Comment: Ora essa Pena, experimenta parar o mongod e correr novamente algo assim: `mongod --dbpath /data/db --rest` ou então se não estiver a especificar nenhum argumento basta  fazer `mongod --rest`

Comment: @AndréVarandas Gênio, deu certo!! você poderia ter repondido a pergunta camarada!! Responda!! Arigato!,Sayonara!! –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB expõe um interface http, através do qual podemos verificar o seu status utilizando a porta 28017.

Para aceder via browser, o comando `--rest` deve ser passado ao `mongod`,
como por exemplo:

`mongo --dbpath /data/db --rest`

Em seguida abra o seu browser:

`http://localhost: 28017/mydb/mycollection/`

**Importante**:
Este interface nunca deverá ser utilizado em ambiente de produção.

Mais informação nessa **página oficial** [Mongodb Http Interfaces](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/)

Answer (score 2):

Edite o arquivo /etc/mongodb.conf

**`sudo nano /etc/mongodb.conf`**

acrescente a linha:

***`rest = true`***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

reinicie o serviço

**`sudo mongod restart`**

Pronto. Agora a porta esta servindo REST.